# COG source in OpenLayers: colored pixels outside its bounding box

Tags: openlayers

I have a map that loads a COG file. When OL renders it I have colored pixels outside the extent of the layer?
The COG has `NaN` as null value.

Here a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/ol-sgekdh?file=/main.js

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

[image]

```js
import GeoTIFF from "ol/source/GeoTIFF.js";
import Map from "ol/Map.js";
import TileLayer from "ol/layer/WebGLTile.js";
import colormap from "colormap";
import OSM from "ol/source/OSM";
import { register } from "ol/proj/proj4";
import proj4 from "proj4";
import { proj4Defs } from "./proj";
import { View } from "ol";

proj4.defs(proj4Defs);
register(proj4);

function getColorStops(name, min, max, steps, reverse) {
  const delta = (max - min) / (steps - 1);
  const stops = new Array(steps * 2);
  const colors = colormap({ colormap: name, nshades: steps, format: "rgba" });
  if (reverse) {
    colors.reverse();
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
    stops[i * 2] = min + i * delta;
    stops[i * 2 + 1] = colors[i];
  }
  return stops;
}

const url = "https://andy-aws.s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/RNBR.tif";

const source = new GeoTIFF({
  normalize: false,
  sources: [
    {
      url: url,
      nodata: NaN
    }
  ]
});

const layer1 = ["band", 1];

const osm = new TileLayer({
  source: new OSM()
});

const layer = new TileLayer({
  source: source,
  style: {
    color: [
      "case",
      // if band 2 == 0, than set it transparent
      ["==", ["band", 2], 0],
      ["color", 0, 0, 0, 0],
      // otherwise, shades of green
      [
        "interpolate",
        ["linear"],
        layer1,
        ...getColorStops("greens", -2, 2, 9, true)
      ]
    ]
  }
});

const view1 = source.getView();

const view2 = new View({
  projection: "EPSG:4326",
  center: [31.8375, -13.12945],
  zoom: 12
});

const map = new Map({
  target: "map",
  layers: [osm, layer],
  view: view2
});

// Register onclick event listener on the map or layer
map.on("click", function (event) {
  var coordinate = event.coordinate;
  console.log("Clicked coordinate:", coordinate);

  const data = layer.getData(event.pixel);
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: It looks OK if the `nodata` commented out and left to default

Comment: @Mike thank you it works. Isn't that the correct way to state it? And the strange thing is that it works in one part of the map, and in another it doesn't. Could it be OL bug?

Comment: I think there are two values in that file which can mean nodata.  Setting `nodata` to either NaN or 0 works if you change the case to `['any', ['==', ['band', 2], 0], ['==', ['band', 1], 0]],`

Answer (score 1):

The COG tif has in its metadata the nodata settings.

I can comment `nodata: NaN` and it works